# Implementing Pusher APNs Notification

Tags: ios, cordova, notifications, pusher

following this [promising tutorial](https://blog.pusher.com/add-real-time-updates-and-native-push-notifications-using-cordova/) from [nickjf89](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3551654/nickjf89) I try to implement Push Notification in a vanilla Cordova project.

Until now, I'm able to get communication with the socket, when I push data from the Pusher console, all works, so I exclude any misconfiguration on Pusher API.

The "only" thing which fail is the actual Push Notification.
Looking at the Push Notification console, I see my request arriving on my cordova channel.
But in the xCode console, I don't see the expected log from `NSLog(@"Received remote notification: %@", userInfo);`

I suspect I got an issue with my `AppDelegate.m` which is below.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"

@import UserNotifications;
#import <PusherSwift/PusherSwift-Swift.h>

@interface AppDelegate ()
@property (nonatomic, retain, readwrite) Pusher *pusher;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];

    self.pusher = [[Pusher alloc] initWithKey:@"here_i_put_my_pusher_app_key"];

    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];

    [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionBadge | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionSound) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        // Enable or disable features based on authorisation.
    }];

    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];

    return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSLog(@"Registered for remote notifications; received device token");
    [[[self pusher] nativePusher] registerWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
    [[[self pusher] nativePusher] subscribeWithInterestName:@"cordova"];
    NSLog(@"Seeems token stuff works");
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    NSLog(@"Received remote notification: %@", userInfo);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, one time again, the issue was between the chair and the keyboard...
I found the fix, it was related to the APNs certificate uploaded on Pusher and the `my-app-name.entitlements` where APS environment was set on production instead of development.

All fixed and functional, great new feature from Pusher!